# Dovecot, Error: Threading lost Message ID

Tags: dovecot, maildir

Dovecot generates `Error: Threading lost Message ID` in dovecot.log
Problem is only with one Maildir. This Maildir cannot be accesed through webmail (in this case Roundcube), error in webmail after log in:

```
Server Error: UID THREAD: Internal error occured. Refer to server log for more information.
```

The only suggestion I've found is here: http://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2013-August/091939.html
but I still don't know what causes the problem, how to fix it and how to avoid it in the future, so any suggestion appreciated.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finaly I've found the solution. Somehow file dovecot.index.thread was corupted and causes the problem. I've deleted file dovecot.index.thread, the file was rebuild then properly, and problem was solved.